# deleting rows from sqlite not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table into which I have no problem inserting data. But when I try to delete a row, it returns 0 count. It does not delete the row. What is wrong with my sql statement?

Table creation

```
final String SQL_CREATE_DOG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DogContract.DogEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                //identification
                DogContract.DogEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_DOG_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_DOG_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_OWNER_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                //position
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_BIRTH_TIME + " BIGINT NOT NULL, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_DEATH_TIME + " BIGINT NOT NULL, " +
                //contact info
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_LASTNAME + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
                //Dog data
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_FOODS + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_TOYS + " TEXT, " +
                //address
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_ADDRESS_1 + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_ADDRESS_2 + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_CITY + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_STATE + " TEXT, " +
                DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_ZIP_CODE + " TEXT" +
                ");";

        sqliteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_DOG_TABLE);
```

Delete query

```
private int deleteByDogTypeAndId(Uri uri) {
    if (null == mOpenHelper) {
        mOpenHelper = new DogDBHelper(getContext());
    }
    final String TABLE_NAME = DogContract.DogEntry.TABLE_NAME;
    final String[] selectionArgs = DogContract.DogEntry.getDogTypeAndDogIdFromUri(uri);
    final String selection = DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_DOG_TYPE + " = ? AND " +
             DogContract.DogEntry.COLUMN_DOG_ID + " = ? ";
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
    if (0 < count) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(DogContract.DogEntry.CONTENT_URI, null);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Some notes. Although I am not showing logging here, I am actually logging the steps. dogType is a String while dogId is a Long. Notice that dogId is different from dbId. dogId is set on the server, whereas dbId is a local db construct.

Comment: Note: although the type of dogId is long, it is actually 5 digits in size, as in `12345` or `45678`.